# Why is If-Modified-Since sent by Firefox but received by PHP blank, only on one server?

Tags: php, apache, http-headers, if-modified-since

I've a fair bit of experience with HTTP, headers, browsers, javascript, PHP, and all this related hoo-hah, but this one has me stumped.

I've written a Javascript RESTful frontend using the Dojo javascript toolkit.  One component of it is a RESTful store that polls the backend for new data items, passing the If-Modified-Since header to the server.  The backend then responds with all items created or updated since that time.  My backend is PHP and reads the $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] value, parses it, and processing continues.

This works flawlessly on my localhost (Ubuntu 13.05, apache2 2.4.6 PHP 5.5.3) in both Chrome and Firefox.  However, on our production server (Centos 6.5 apache2 2.2.23 PHP 5.3.17), Chrome works fine, but Firefox has a problem.

What I see is that Firefox sends the If-Modified-Since header correctly and with normal date format, however, the PHP  $_SERVER variable contains HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE but the value appears to be empty, and getallheaders() returns an array without that header, but with all other headers.  My question is, what could be causing this, and how should it be fixed?

Googling on this subject leads me to lots of people who don't know how to use Last-Modified to cause the browser to send If-Modified-Since in the first place, or how to use it if it is sent.  I cannot find anyone else with the problem that it is sent, but not received on the server, for just one type of browser.

I cannot capture the headers from the Firefox Network Monitor as text easily (well done Mozilla) but trust me, If-Modified-Since is there, with value e.g. `Sat, 08 Feb 2014 10:29:14 GMT`, nestled in between `Accept-Encoding` and `Content-Type`.

Code on the backend:

```
$l->log('test for header from user agent ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . '...');
$headers = getallheaders();
foreach ($headers as $name => $value) {
        $l->log("Saw header $name => $value");
}
if (array_key_exists('HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE', $_SERVER)) {
        $mod = $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'];
        $l->log('header exists: (' . $mod . ')');
        // handle here
} else {
        $l->log('No IF_MODIFIED_SINCE found.');
}
```

example logging:

```
Feb 08 10:33:24  [info] test for header from user agent Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0...
Feb 08 10:33:24  [info] Saw header Host => www.premierrange.co.uk
Feb 08 10:33:24  [info] Saw header User-Agent => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0
Feb 08 10:33:24  [info] Saw header Accept => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Feb 08 10:33:24  [info] Saw header Accept-Language => en-US,en;q=0.5
Feb 08 10:33:24  [info] Saw header Accept-Encoding => gzip, deflate
Feb 08 10:33:24  [info] Saw header Content-Type => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Feb 08 10:33:24  [info] Saw header X-Requested-With => XMLHttpRequest
Feb 08 10:33:24  [info] Saw header Referer => http://www.premierrange.co.uk/obfuscated
Feb 08 10:33:24  [info] Saw header Cookie => obfuscated
Feb 08 10:33:24  [info] Saw header Connection => keep-alive
Feb 08 10:33:24  [info] Saw header Via => HTTP/1.1 NetScaler, HTTP/1.1 NetScaler
Feb 08 10:33:24  [info] header exists: ()
Feb 08 10:33:24  [info] HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE  strtotime gives  turning that into date string gives 1970-01-01 01:00:00
```

As you can see, an `array_key_exists` test returns true, but the value is empty, yet `getallheaders()` appears to return an array of headers that does not include `If-Modified-Since`.

Any clues, before I tear even more hair out?

Comment: Apache [can unset headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#header), it might be worth your while to delve through it's exact configuration on that Centos server. (Yes, I take it Chrome works fine, but Firefox doesn't, but headers can be unset based on all kinds of conditions. It may be an old workaround for some perceived Firefox problem). If that does not help you, you could try to log the header with [`%{If-Modified-Since}i`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats) to see what the webserver thinks it is.

Comment: Thanks Wrikken, good ideas.  I tried this config: ``<IfModule setenvif.c>
        SetEnvIf If-Modified-Since .* Foo-Modified-Since=If-Modified-Since
</IfModule>
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/premierrange.co.uk-custom "%f %q if-modified-since: '%{If-Modified-Since}i' foo '%{Foo-Modified-Since}e'"`` and got some useful logging like ``restTonic.php ?date_closed=null if-modified-since: '-' foo '-'`` which seems to show the header is missing even at the time SetEnvIf copies it to my Foo-* variable.  Until a solution is found, my workaround is sending a custom header If-Updated-Since.

Comment: Also, I have searched the entire ``/usr/local/apache/conf`` dir tree for any mention of If-Modified-Since (case insensitive) and found nothing.  Also searched the restTonic source in ``/usr/local/lib/php/tonic/`` and cannot see anything in there that might be messing with headers, and done a getallheaders() check in my top level restTonic.php file before including any Tonic php files that may muddy the headers, still no If-Modified-Since (which isn't surprising given the very low level SetEnvIf test).

Comment: Hm, are you a 100% sure you're connecting to this sever _directly_, no proxy/balancing/whatever in between? No proxy config in the browser itself? This would really be the moment I reach for `tcpdump` on both the client & the server just to do some sanity checking.